# How can I change the size of the Mozilla Firefox screen?

Tags: firefox, window

I accidentally made Firefox take up the whole screen but it is not in full screen mode. How do I shrink it back down so I can see other open windows?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>LeftMouseButton</kbd> and drag to move almost any window on a screen so that the controls (close, minimize, maximize) appear in your view.

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd> together and a menu will appear. Then press the appropriate key for "restore" or "resize".

Answer (score 0):

Move cursor to the top left of your screen. There you should see an X, -, or box. Click on the - sign to shrink the screen down. The box maximizes the screen and the X closes Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Press `F11` and you can see fullscreen changed to normal window.
If that is not working may be firefox is not is not responding. Press ctrl+shift+t and a terminal will show up. and type the command `killall firefox`. When you open firefox again it will be in normal size. Hope this helps.

Comment: The question explicitly mentions that Firefox is *not* in fullscrean mode.

Comment: but he can try that. It happened to me too. There was no title bar to close firefox and it was in full screen. I tried F11 no change. And killed the process and restarted. That is the best in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

First you check u in full screen or not click the maximize button, go to top or corner browser if it is in full screen you cant not able edit it if it is not in full screen u can see the re-sizer arrow using that you can re-size it .